# AJAX dyamic content "event delegation" replacement for "each"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, momentjs

I'm implementing AJAX "load more" pagination on a website.

In order for .click() events to work for dynamically loaded content, I replaced all the .click() code with...

```
$(document).on('click', ".selector", function (event){
```

That's all working fine for clickable stuff.

Now I'm trying to get some non-click based init code working in the same way as well.  This is the old version of my code that works for normal non-AJAX content:

```
var now = moment();
$('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));
    $(e).html(time.from(now));
    $(e).attr('title', time.format('D MMM YYYY h:mma'));
});
```

How would I get this code to also work on the dynamically loaded `<time>` tags?

I tried the following, but it's obviously wrong (using this code none of the `<time>` tags work at all):

```
var now = moment();
$(document).on('each', 'time', function (event){
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));
    $(e).html(time.from(now));
    $(e).attr('title', time.format('D MMM YYYY h:mma'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require the logic in your first block is correct - you just need to execute it again when the new `<time>` elements have been added to the DOM. The easiest way to do this is to extract the logic to a function, something like this:

```
function setTime($container) {
  $container = $container || $(document);
  var now = moment();
  $container.find('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));
    $(e).html(time.from(now));
    $(e).attr('title', time.format('D MMM YYYY h:mma'));
  });
}

setTime(); // on load

$.ajax({
  url: '/foo',
  success: function(html) {
    var $container = $('.container').append(html);
    setTime($container); // after the AJAX call
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add back your listener to the newly add time. 
Jquery is setting it's listener once at the loading of the page that's why they are not accessible once you loaded them. I suggest using a method to add your listener and simple recall the method at the end of your success callback.